# Python print a list of strings horizontally without quotations or brackets

Tags: python

I have a list

```
    l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

When I run print l1 it returns:

```
    ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

When I try

```
    for a in l1
        print ' '.join(map(str,a))
```

I get

```
    a  
    b  
    c  
    d  
    e
```

What I want to get though is

```
    a b c d e
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `join` is doing is  it returns a string, which is the concatenation of the strings in the sequence (in your case `l1`). The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

```
>>> l1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> ' '.join(l1)
'a b c d e'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, you can also add a comma after the print statement, to cause the next one to print on the same line.

```
for a in l1:
    print a,
```