# Python evaluating "eval" windows paths wrongly

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, eval

I am trying to use eval to convert a string representing a list of file paths to an actual list.

However, it seems to me that eval ruins that path. See the following code:

*Code executed in Pycharm Python console*

```
>>> _path  = '["c:\\path\\to\\knowwhere"]'
>>> eval(_path)
['c:\\path\to\\knowwhere']
```

As shown above, the eval process removes one `'\'` making it a tab in the string, and thus cannot find the file.

Is there any way around this or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Note:
`ast.literal_eval()` does the same.

I'm using the latest Python3.10, and Pycharm IDE

EDIT:
This also fails

```
>>> cmd = """_path = ['C:\\path\\to\\knowwhere']\nprint(_path)"""
>>> exec(cmd)
['C:\\path\to\\knowwhere']
```

And the above could be an external script, but would not work.

regards

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be a better way. Also Im not sure what "making it a tab in the string" means

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/confused-about-backslashes-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Bear in mind that the "_path" in your source code is ultimately parsed **twice** for escape sequences: once when the source code is parsed, and once when `eval` processes the resulting string object. So you need either quadruple-backslashes, or keep your double-backslashes and use a raw string (like `r"foo\\bar"`).

Comment: Also, how do you get this string in first place?

Comment: @ajgrinds In the ultimate `['c:\\path\to\\knowwhere']`, `\to` is tab+o, not backslash+t+o.

Comment: what I do not understand is that the "\\" is preserved partially. It is only where there is a 't' in the name that it converts it to a TAB

Comment: That's because `\p` and `\k` can't be interpreted as escape sequences, so they're treated as backslash+p and backslash+k. Contrast those with `\t`, `\n` and so on, which do have interpretations as escape sequences. For example, `'["c:\\path\\to\\nowhere"]'` ends up as `['c:\\path\to\nowhere']` with a tab and a newline.

Comment: Well, all in all if you make a small script with a windows path. It will fail in eval or exec.

Comment: Yep, I would try to find a solution that didn't require eval or exec. Either put a list directly in the source code of the script, or have something like a newline-delimited string that you can just convert to a list using `.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you *have* to do it this way, use raw strings:

```
>>> _path  = '[r"c:\\path\\to\\knowwhere"]'
>>> mylist = eval(_path)
>>> print(mylist[0])
c:\path\to\knowwhere
```

But you'll sleep better if you write out your lists of paths properly (don't print the list with one `print`, use a loop to print each path), so that you can read them back in with `readlines()` and avoid eval altogether. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788985/python-print-a-list-of-strings-horizontally-without-quotations-or-brackets) will help.

Comment: That does not work unless you use raw print

Comment: MY example is just that a simple example. The code where this is needed is much more complex and just adding raw print is not an option.

Comment: You do not need raw print for anything. The `print()` is just to show you what the `eval` puts in the string.. What you do with it from then on is your business (and out of scope for this question).